# Can't resolve all parameters error when TranslateService injected in Angular 8

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am trying to use ngx-translate module for translation, but when I inject the TranslateService in app.component.ts, I get the below warning.

```
Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent in ./rsa/src/app/app.component.ts: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
```

I have other services injected which work fine.

My ngx-translate versions are below:

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
```

I tried using @Inject token, but it is not working. What could be the issue?

**Update**:

For some strange reason, when I restarted VSCode, the warning has gone now. Maybe it was a caching issue. Checking if issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

- Are you sure that `I18n` is the problem?
- Have you defined every service in the component's `constructor` in the `providers` array of the module that declares that component?
- If the service in question is not within the modules `providers` array, is the service defined as an injectable `providedIn: 'root'` (thus automatically instantiated properly)?

  Something like:

```js
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [],
  providers: [ I18n ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core/v/12.0.0 - I have followed all the instruction in the npm page.Strangely when I restarted VSCode, the warning went away for now. I will check and see if the issue persists. Maybe it is a caching issue.

Comment: VSCode tends to die if you rebuild `node_modules` while it is running. I usually close it before wiping `node_modules` :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the parameter of constructor:

```
constructor(private window: Window) {
}
```

when I remove it, localization works.

Answer (score -1):

run `npm install`

Then import `TranslateModule.forRoot()` in your `AppModule`.